# Display Characters in Java

Tags: java, character

How do I get java to read and all of the characters from a word of any length?

I know that I have to use the .charAt(x) method, but how can I get the characters from a word of any length (eg: 2 or more letters)

Also: how would I then get it to build this word up slowly again, as in display the letters slowly building up the letter (i am aware i need to use System.out.println())

eg: if my word was sugar, java would display:
s
then: su
then: sug
then: suga
then: sugar

Thank You

Comment: A for loop that uses the length of the string as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

use `toCharArray()` method of String and iterate through the array returned by that method, use `StrinfBuilder` to incrementally build it again, put thread to sleep for the amount of milliseconds that suits you.

```
char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


for(char c : chars) {
  builder.append(c);
  System.out.print(builder.toString() + " ");
  Thread.currentThread().sleep(milliseconds);
}
```

Comment: thank you, this solves my problem almost perfectly, however you forgot the "ln" on "System.out.print(builder.toString());"

Comment: hang on, just re read the assignment, and it is meant to build up the word slowly on the same line (badly worded assignment), so i tried removing the ln, and it didnt work, any idea?

Comment: it printed ssusugsugasugar

Comment: Yes I fixed it now. Don' append whiotespace just do + " " in System.out.println() (I updated the answer again)

Comment: hang on i explained it badly (i'm not really very good at explaining, sorry), it needs to show the s, then the u is added, then the g is added, then the a is added, then the r is added to give one word saying sugar (sugar being the example word)

Comment: HAHA! I have it, dont worry, thank you for your help, and sorry that I wasted your time